# File hosting service that encrypts files without failure

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing, encryption

The first service that everyone will think of is Dropbox, which I love *dearly* and will continue support (**1 year for me and syncing strong**).

I read on [Dropbox Blog](http://blog.dropbox.com/?p=821) as well as [other](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2674369) [sources](http://pastebin.com/yBKwDY6T) that there was an authentication bug that allowed temporary access to an account without the correct password. It seems to be under control now and I bear no malice to Dropbox and their team. Failures and bugs are inevitable, I can deal with that.

As it stands Dropbox is very lightweight and simple for getting files across various devices. Thus, as incompetent as I am, I think I might continue placing semi-sensitive info up there in my box. I know that I can encrypt files into an image but I am sure this will choke the partial file changes. I know I can buy hosting as well, but this does not take care of multiple devices.

*How can I encrypt my files on Dropbox to be protected from failures that leave authentication open? (i.e. is there a way to add a second layer without making it too complicated? I need to explain this to my family as well)*

or

*Where can I host files that will be encrypted and **in the event of a failure in the system, the files stay encrypted**?*

Of course, the service must match what was mentioned above

- Multiple Devices: Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android (In my case: Windows,Mac,iOS at least)
- Sharing among users (this will be hard after all those friends I have referred to Dropbox)
- Files always available from the website
- Revisions on files with history
- Preferably 1-2 GB free (Though I don't mind premium services)
- Not complex (Simple UI, Simple workflow)
- Preferably IP listing (with timestamp) of every access of the service

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12491/is-there-an-encrypting-dropbox-wrapper

Comment: Still losing out on the [partial syncing](https://www.dropbox.com/help/8)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to relax atleast couple of those restrictions. Security + Sharing + Multiple devices + Easy - I doubt any service exists which meets all of your criteria.

Having said that, [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) is probably the closest that comes to meeting your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout WUALA https://www.wuala.com/en/

5GB Free and mostly the same functions as dropbox, but completely encrypted all the way.